# Sitecore CRM Connect 1.1 Issues connecting to MS Dynamics

Tags: configuration

I'm currently following the configuration guide for Crm Connect v1.1 and the instructions seem to cover connecting to a web based instance of Dynamics but not an on premise instance via AD.

The following link runs through setting the connection string

http://integrationsdn.sitecore.net/DynamicsCrmConnect/v1.1/getting-started/add-crm-connection-string.html

I've set my connection string accordingly and now have

```
connectionString="url=http://{server_ip}:{port}/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc;Domain={AD_Domain};user id={username};password={password};authentication type=2"
```

When testing the connection string, I receive the following error

The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.

The previous documentation on CRM Connect indicated that the authentication type for AD should be 0, but this goes against the recommendation in the docs (and doesn't work anyway)

Anyone have an example of a connection string that works for CrmConnect 1.1 when connecting via AD ?

Comment: Can you try to have just this url http://{server_ip}:{port}/XRMServices in the connection strings

Comment: Have you tried switching to https?

Comment: Tried both of these, no luck !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. Turns out the issue was down to configuration on the Dynamics side. I tried with a free trial of Dynamics 365 and was able to connect successfully with the connection string I displayed originally

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this format of connection string.

```
<add name="dynamicsCRM" connectionString="Url=[crm url you connected to crm]; Username=[email you connected to crm]; Password=[password you connected to crm];" />
```

I do not use "XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc".
Here is my. Tested. Works well.

```
<add name="dynamicsCRM" connectionString="Url=https://sitecoretest9.crm4.dynamics.com; Username=[my email]; Password=[my password];" />
```