# Sitecore Microsoft Dynamics CRM Security Provider 2.1 fails on Sitecore 8

Tags: dynamics-crm-module

I have an issue  with the following Module "Microsft Dynamics CRM Security Provider 2.1.2" 
I´m using Sitecore 8.0 with Microsoft Dynamics Office 365(online on Microsoft)
I read all the documentation, and I could not find anything Related to OFFICE 365(Dynamics online) 
Connection string Syntax :(https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/dynamics%20crm%20campaign%20integration/dynamics_crm_security_provider_module_guide_for_sc60-70-a4.pdf)

The release notes say that works with Office 365 (https://dev.sitecore.net/en/Downloads/Dynamics%20CRM%20Security%20Provider/2%201/Dynamics%20CRM%20Security%20Provider%202%201%202/Release%20Notes)

If I use the old crm connection string syntax. it works, and if I click on "user Manager", Sitecore User Manager works(get all CRM contacts)

**OLD CRM Connection String SYNTAX**
  https://crm.crmdev.XXXX.com/XXXX-dev/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc;user id=Sitecore-myusername;password=pass@12345;organization=XXXX-DEV;authentication type=0" />

**NEW OFFICE 365 CONNECTION STRING SYNTAX**
If I use the new connection string, my Sitecore "user Manager" is not able to get CRM contacts

https://clientsandbox.api.crm3.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc;user id=myuser;password=myusername2017;authtype=Office365" />

The documentation tells me that works, but this is not the case it´s not 
The logs files complaints about the structure of the ConnectionString

-Missing Organization Param

-Missing authentication type

But even if I adapt, still not working
Do anyone knows if this Provider works with "Dynamics ONLINE Office 365"

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting errors in the logs?

Comment: Yes, I´m the new CRM Connection string Syntax is not recognized

Comment: @Jose, can you give a shot and see the answer from this post - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2842/sitecore-crm-connect-1-1-issues-connecting-to-ms-dynamics

Comment: Hi Vinicius, it does not work, if I remove the "organization" parameter, the log files complaint, "organization is missing"

Comment: can you edit your question and add the log entries?

Comment: Problem Solved : Solution : If you are using just Sitecore CRM Provider, you should use "authentication type=2" , if you are using Microsoft.Xrm.dl, you should use authtype=Office365 , if you are using both dlls on the project(since then do different stuff) , you can use "authentication type=2;authtype=Office365", Sitecore Helped me on this Issue , but i suggested then to use the Microsoft Standard, to avoid this type of issue

Comment: @Jose, please add as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem Solved**

**Solution:** If you are using just Sitecore CRM Provider, you should use
`"authentication type=2"`, if you are using Microsoft.Xrm.dl then you should use `authtype=Office365`, if you are using both dlls on the project (since they do different stuff), you can use `"authentication type=2;authtype=Office365"`

Sitecore helped me on this issue (on the Sitecore part) but I suggested then to use the Microsoft Standard, to avoid this type of issue, anyway the solution would be using both Sitecore and Microsoft Parameter on the same ConnectionString

**Final Connection string would be**

`url=https://CHANGEME.api.crm3.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc;user id=CHANGEME;password=CHANGEME;authtype=Office365;authentication type=2`